# Finding MacAddress from IP Address in a platform independent way

Tags: macos, cross-platform, ip

I need to findout the mac address of the device from which my device gets TCP requests, I ll be getting the ip address of the device by tcp endpoint but i need to find out the mac address of the device.My application will be running on both windows and linux, so please suggest me a cross platform method to find the mac address.. Any boost libraries will help me doing the same??

Comment: The other device, that is a device which is remote, i.e. not on the same local network?

Comment: the other device is also in the same network..

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you can't find the MAC address for any network interface that is not on the same local area network.  That information is not transmitted beyond the router.

There is a command line tool called `arp` that is available on Unix and also Windows that will list  IP addresses and MAC addresses of interfaces that have been in communication with your PC. i.e.

```
arp -a
```

on Windows gives something like:

```
Interface: 9.175.198.236 --- 0x2
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  9.175.198.129         00-1b-53-46-fa-7f     dynamic
```

and on a Unix-alike looks like:

```
foo.bar.com (10.27.68.72) at 00:50:56:AE:00:0B [ether] on eth0
baz.bar.com (10.27.68.77) at 00:50:56:AE:00:10 [ether] on eth0
? (10.27.68.1) at 00:50:5A:1B:44:01 [ether] on eth0
```

You can try invoking it and parsing the output programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, but how do invoke the arp command from my C++ program?? Not really familiar with this.. :(

Comment: @Achuthananda MP: On OS X and other Unix-alikes, you would use fork and exec. I don't know how you would do it on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

arp source code is available in the below link, take the piece of code that interests you! It is c code so it should work fine.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-328/arp.tproj/arp.c

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that at TCP layer, you don't know the MAC addresses.

For your case, I guess you can do two things:

1. use arp or write a piece of code similar to arp which looks for MAC given the IP address. 
   The problem with this approach is that it won't work in cases when the source is in another network.
2. write your server in such a way that it requests for this information from the client sending TCP request. This can be done post TCP establishment. The client should also be able to look up the machine's MAC address for the given IP.